# Wide Swing PMOS Cascode Biasing

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, pmos, biasing, cascode

I would like to know if someone has designed a wide swing PMOS cascode biasing circuit (as attached in the picture) in 16nm FinFET, especially for IO devices having 1.8V supply. I see that theoretically it should be possible to keep M2 in saturation as long as Vov2<= |Vth1|, but practically it is looking impossible to keep M2 in saturation especially at fast hot corners.[image]